# How do I update a drupal module without deleting it first?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

How do I upload a new version of a module to my site? If I choose "Install new module" through the administration page I get a message that the module already is installed. There are two work arounds that I have found, but none of them seems ideal and the way you are supposed to do it.

1. I can delete the old module first, and then upload and install the new version. However, if the modules has data associated with it, then this data will be lost.
2. I can replace the module files on the server. This doesn't seem such a clean way to do it, I would rather follow a more standard process, if there is any.

So what is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make a back-up...just in case.
2. Put your site in maintance mode.
3. Overwrite your module files with updated version (delete old module files first)
4. run /update.php from browser or from console run `drush updb` if you have drush installed (to make database changes if any and similar stuff).
5. Put your site in "normal" mode again...check if everything is ok.

https://www.drupal.org/node/250790

Comment: Yep seems to be official way of doing it... Thanks for the link... Just feel I have to say I'm a bit surprised that there is no way to update a module using the UI. I mean, I can install a new module, but I can't update one...

Answer (score 1):

MilanG's answer is incorrect on step 3. You don't overwrite, you need to remove the existing modules files, then put the new module files in it's place. This is because new module releases may include removed files, and sometimes if those files aren't removed you have problems.

So...

1. Make a backup (drush site-archive)
2. Put site in maintenance mode (drush vset maintenance_mode 0)
3. Delete the old module's directory entirely (rm -fr path/to/modulename)
4. Download the latest version of the module (drush dl modulename)
5. Run update.php (drush -y updb)
6. Turn off maintenance mode (drush vset maintenance_mode 1)

With drush it's pretty easy to just write a wrapper script and run that by module, so that you could do "drush update-module modulename" and those other steps happen.